# prevent css from breaking sentence on dash

Tags: html, css

How do I prevent a string like this:

```
1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg
```

From getting broken on the dashes? aka

```
1ffa6fyfguyyg-
gfbhf-rtydrygd-
dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg
```

I've tried the following code:

```
.filename{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 95%;
}
```

But no luck.

basically what I'm trying to do is display a filename in a `<td>` element and if its too long add the three dots. it works fine on some filenames but on ones like this it just breaks the name on the dash

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please show table markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `display: block;` to override the table display format. If this isn't an option, consider moving away from tables altogether. They often have strange interactions with other CSS rules.

```css
.container {
  height:200px;
  max-width:10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="container">
  block-of-text-with-breaks-but-has-dashes
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: display: block; fixed it thank you! at first i wanted to use the nowrap attribute like @Vinicius Cainelli suggested but i found its not supported in html so display: block; will have to do

Comment: With `display:block;`, the next `<td>` will be placed below.

Comment: @Maarti this is why i suggested moving away from tables. You might look into some other option for orginizing infomation such as grid layout or flex box

Comment: If you have to use table, you can look at my answer with `table-layout: fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

Add `table-layout: fixed;` to your `<table>`, here is an example:

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 50px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
     <td>1ffa6fyfguyyg-gfbhf-rtydrygd-dry6r-5r-rtd.jpg</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```